# What is wrong when I use Length[{a, b, c}] == 3 in this code?

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting

I want to creat the triples `(a,b,c)` so that `Length[{a, b, c}] == 3`, I tried

```
 Table[If[Length[{a, b, c}] == 3, {a, b, c}, Nothing], {a, 3}, {b, 3}, {c, 3}];
    Flatten[%, 2]
```

I get

> {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1,
> 3, 1}, {1, 3, 2}, {1, 3, 3}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2,
> 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 3}, {3, 1,
> 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 1, 3}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 2}, {3, 2, 3}, {3, 3,
> 1}, {3, 3, 2}, {3, 3, 3}}

The result incorrect, e.g, the triple `{3, 3, 3}`.  What is wrong in my code?

Comment: `{braces}` in Mathematica do not indicate a set, they indicate a `List`.  Lists can have multiple copies of the same element, so `{a,b,c}` _always_ has 3 elements no matter the values of a, b, or c.

Comment: If you're looking for all length-3 unique orderings of the elements 1, 2, and 3 you should probably use `Permutations[{1, 2, 3}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
Table[If[CountDistinct[{a, b, c}] == 3, {a, b, c}, Nothing], {a, 
   3}, {b, 3}, {c, 3}];
Flatten[%, 2]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}}

Or

```
Table[If[a != b != c, {a, b, c}, Nothing], {a, 3}, {b, 3}, {c, 3}];
Flatten[%, 2]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}}

Answer (score 2):

Add `DeleteDuplicates` or `Union`.

```
Table[If[Length[DeleteDuplicates@{a, b, c}] == 3, {a, b, c}, 
   Nothing], {a, 3}, {b, 3}, {c, 3}];
Flatten[%, 2]
```

> `{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}}`

Answer (score 2):

Some variations:

```
p1 = Table[
   If[Last /@ Tally[{a, b, c}] == {1, 1, 1}, {a, b, c}, Nothing], {a, 
    3}, {b, 3}, {c, 3}] // Flatten[#, 2] &

p2 = Table[
   If[Values@Counts[{a, b, c}] == {1, 1, 1}, {a, b, c}, Nothing], {a, 
    3}, {b, 3}, {c, 3}] // Flatten[#, 2] &


p3 = Table[
   If[CountDistinct[{a, b, c}] == 3, {a, b, c}, Nothing], {a, 3}, {b, 
    3}, {c, 3}] // Flatten[#, 2] &


p4 = Table[
   If[UnsameQ @@ {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, Nothing], {a, 3}, {b, 3}, {c, 
    3}] // Flatten[#, 2] &
```

---

*Result:*

> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}}

Comment: `p3` had already been posted as I uploaded my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `Array` and `Cases`:

```
f[l_] := If[CountDistinct[l] == 3, l, Nothing]

Cases[Array[Function[{x, y, z}, f@{x, y, z}], Array[3 &, 3]], {__Integer}, ∞]

(*{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}}*)
```

Or simpler, as @Syed suggests (Thanks, @Syed!):

```
Array[f[{#1, #2, #3}] &, {3, 3, 3}] // Flatten[#, 2] &

(*{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}}*)
```

Comment: Why not just: `Array[f[{#1, #2, #3}] &, {3, 3, 3}] // Flatten[#, 2] &` ?

Comment: Very nice, @Syed! :-)